# Drop Down Being Pushed To the Right?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, nav

For some reason, my drop down menu is being pushed to the right. It's supposed to open up directly below the link someone is hovering over, but it opens about 30px to the right and I can't figure out why. You can see the issue in action when you scroll over "Work" on my website: http://www.noellesnotes.com

My code:

CSS

```
ul.site-navigation {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.site-navigation li a{
    padding: 50px 0 47px 0;
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif, Georgia;
    width: 125px;
    float: left;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
    color: rgb(82,82,82);
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

ul.site-navigation > li {
    position: relative;
    width: 125px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.site-navigation a:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(4,141,195);
    text-shadow: rgb(200, 200, 200) 1px 1px 0px;
    padding: 97px 0 0 0;
}

ul.site-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
     height: 50px;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1000;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}

ul.site-navigation ul li {
     float: none;
 }

ul.site-navigation li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

ul.site-navigation ul li a {
     font-weight: regular;
     font-size: 16px;
    text-shadow: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 5px 10px 0 0;
}

ul.site-navigation ul li a:hover {
    font-weight: regular;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-shadow: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
}

.site-title a {
    color: rgb(185,40,141);
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 63px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: #FFF 1px 1px,#ccc 2px 2px;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

.site-branding {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    font-family: 'Lato', verdana, san-serif;
    font-size: 6em;
    text-shadow:1px -1px rgba(242,141,89,0.2);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-image: url('http://www.noellesnotes.com/wp-content/themes/portfolio/images/lights.jpg');
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
               <ul class="site-navigation">
                    <li><a href="/bio/">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/portfolio/">Work</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="/portfolio/seventeen/">Seventeen.com</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/portfolio/1dc/">One Direction Connection</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, the problem is the 1.5em left margin for li > ul that you have defined if your theme's style.css file, which applies to the ul.submenu element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a left margin on all uls that are direct children of lis. (li > ul {margin-left:1.5em})

Add Something like this to your css to override that for your menu:

```
ul.site-navigation > li > ul {
   margin-left:-2.75em
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its natural because li tag has ul tag
You can use margin-left:-2px to fix this